# How to clean and build NetBeans project that uses MySQL with JDBC and Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARgk.png) I have limited knowledge about MySQL and NetBeans and am still in the learning process. I have made a project where the user has to login with the correct credentials to access other Jframe forms. The project works perfectly when I debug the project and run it in the NetBeans IDE itself. However, when I make the .jar file, the GUI for the Login form loads but nothing happens when I try to login.
In NetBeans, under Services, I have the following connection to the database
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bakery_System?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]
MAC OSX 10.11.2 and NetBeans 8.0.2
What should I do?

Comment: Does it show any error message while login? Please share the error message. ( or catch the exception - define a try-catch block-  and display/log the error message.)

Comment: @AbdulRazak No error message

Comment: @AbdulRazak I have added the error message that i'm getting after i put a try-catch block

Comment: You need "lib"  folder to run the jar file perfectly, because the MySQL connector is in Lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the "lib" folder to run the jar file. NetBeans put all the required Libraries into the lib folder after building the application.